# unknown make model and year

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

enter image description here![image]

Can someone please help me identify this frame? I have tried searching the net for same lugs design but I can not find anything that is similar to the lugs of this frame.

Comment: It's a bike, probably from the 80s.  The lugs look pretty much standard to me.

Comment: Pretty much looks like mine, in a different color. Mine is a Flandria (Belgian manufacturer). Not sure which year though. I'll post a picture of it tonight. Although I guess many frames of that time look alike.

Comment: Are there any decals, badges, or writing anywhere on the frame that we can't see? If there are, edit in some close-ups. If not, the comment from @DanielRHicks is likely to be the best anybody will be able to nail it down.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell anything from the photo but it's definitely a low level frame, most likely from the late 1970s. The giveaways are:

1. The thickness of the lugs. Good quality lugs (such as Nervex or Henry James) are much thinner. A top level builder will thin the lugs even further. Those are cheap stamped lugs.
2. The square ends of the bottom bracket lugs.
3. Crimped seat/chain stays rather than domed ends at the dropouts.
4. No derailleur hanger on the drive side dropout - a very common sight on inexpensive European bikes from the 1970s which gave the factories more flexibility in production (dropouts really didn't become standardized until after the advent of SIS in 1984 - prior to that you sometimes needed a different hanger/dropout for a Huret Jubilee derailleur than a Campy NR derailleur, for example)
5. The chainstay has double cable loops for the rear derailleur. Bikes built after the early to mid 80s only had one.
6. It has brake cable housing loop braze-ons. These didn't really become standard - especially on lower bikes - until the mid to late 1970s. Prior to that builders were afraid that heating the thinner sections of a tube would weaken them which is why when you look at top of the line racing bikes in the 1960s and even early 70s they still had clamp-on brake cable guides, water bottles, etc. Even Eddy Merckx's Tour winning bike had clamp-on water bottles.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a "[Украина](https://www.google.bg/search?q=%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE&biw=1024&bih=485&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=_kQVVba_MYHkUqG3hAg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ)". They are quite cheap and also very popular in Bulgaria. My dad had one of those back in the days. I see this has speeds. Shifters are very uncomfortable though...

Comment: It also looks exactly like my old Nishiki.  It's a very generic design.

Comment: Seat stays on Ukraina don't have angled tops.